# 401 error when connecting to Pusher from React Native

Tags: react-native, real-time, pusher, http-status-code-401, pusher-js

I am trying to get subscribe to a Pusher channel from React Native, however, I am getting a 401 error.

I have read that it could be an error with server time settings but have made sure that is correct. The connection works perfectly using Laravel Echo and when I have tested it on expo.

The only thing I have which I slightly different is my timezone is Europe/London and currently an hour ahead of UTC. When I go to the Pusher debug console all times are UTC.

Here is my code if anyone has any ideas:

```
PusherInit(){
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    let chat = 'private-chat.' + this.state.chat_id;
    var pusher = new Pusher('...........', {
      authEndpoint: 'https://snippie.co.uk/api/pusher-auth',
        auth: {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': this.state.token
            }
        },
      cluster: 'eu',
      encrypted: true
    });

    const channel = pusher.subscribe(chat);

    channel.bind('Message_Received',
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    );

    channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function(status) {
        console.log (status);
        if(status == 408 || status == 503){
          // retry?
        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change your headers to:

```
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
}
```

Or

```
pusher.config.auth.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.state.token;
```